# Using Simple Injector for Dependency Injection, how do you reference a Unit Of Work object to persist data?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

This is a beginner's question about persisting data using a unit of work, repository, and a service with Simple Injector.  If the repository asks for an `IUnitOfWorkAsync` and the service asks for a `Repository<>`, how would you call `UnitOfWork.Save()?` from either the service layer or the Controller layer that called it?

I know I could create a Singleton Unit Of Work, then ask for a reference to the unit of work at the service level, but I don't want to do this because different controllers need to save data differently.  (I also tried getting a `IUnitOfWorkAsync` reference in the service but it was a different object and SaveChanges had no effect.

I've registered these with Simple Injector:

```
container.Register<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof(IRepositoryAsync<>), typeof(Repository<>));
container.Register(typeof(IHelpService), typeof(HelpService));
```

This is my Repository and my Service:

```
// For each repository like CustomerRepository, OrderRepository
// additional comma separated parameters to the HelpService as necessary
public Repository(IDataContextAsync context, IUnitOfWorkAsync uow)

public HelpService(IRepositoryAsync<HelpTopics> repository) : base(repository) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

> If the repository asks for an IUnitOfWorkAsync and the service asks for a Repository<>, how would you call UnitOfWork.Save()? from either the service layer or the Controller layer that called it?

You don't want to let controllers call `Save` since this is not their responsibility. Neither do you want the services to call `Save` method, because this leads to code duplication and makes it easy to forget calling `Save`.

The solution is to have an intermediate layer that is invisible to both the services and the controllers that allows you save the unit of work and this should be without code duplication.

One way to achieve this is to adapt your application design accordingly. The most effective design I found is [this one](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), where every use case gets its own message in the system, and you encapsulate the business logic for such use case in a single class that implements a generic interface.

That design allows the creation of decorators that can wrap every business operation and call `UnitOfWork.Save()` when the operation finished successfully.

Again, the answer lies in [this design](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Comment: Does your answer imply that the UOW should provide references to the repositories related to it rather than multiple repositories referring to a single UOW? I assume this implies a Service Locator to create instances of repos in the UOW for which Handlers would provide an alternative?  Would [link](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key) be similar thinking or am I missing it entirely? The part I'm missing is how does your `MoveCustomerCommandHandler` reference the repositories (assuming eventual consistency?)

Comment: @Dr.Zim: You can go both ways with this and neither one is bad. Either way, this doesn't imply Service Locator *at all*. In case your UoW is nothing more than a collection of repostories, your UoW implementation can be located inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This way that implementation can depend directly on the `Container`. The use of the Container inside the Composition Root is [not in implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).

Comment: A `MoveCustomerCommandHandler` can either depend on the UoW or on a specific repository. Whether or not you use eventual consistency is irrelevant to this.

Comment: I probably incorrectly mentioned eventual consistency to explain why I have multiple repositories depending on a unit of work instead of using a single repository representing a nested aggregate root.  I'm certainly trying to avoid using a service locator in the UOW to create repositories for my service so that the repositories and the UOW refer to the same data context.

Comment: Even using a handler or injected in to a handler, how do you ensure the UOW and the repositories use the same data context injected in to them without using a singleton data context?  The Service( Repository( UOW( Context))) currently references different data contexts when they should reference one.  Plus, I'll somehow need to reference the UOW.Save().  I started rewiring the UOW to produce repository references which lead to the service locator.